# How to use build in "period" variable?

Tags: pine-script

I want to use "period" variable, as in manual -https://www.tradingview.com/pine-script-reference/#var_period

```
//@version=4
...
resolutionPeriod = 0
if period == '1'
    resolutionPeriod = 1440
if period == '5'
    resolutionPeriod = 288 
...
```

I was getting error Undeclared identifier `period`

Comment: You are actually referring to documentation for pine v3. For v4 doc is here https://www.tradingview.com/pine-script-reference/v4/#var_timeframe{dot}period

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should use `timeframe.period` build-in variable.

I, personally, read the reference manual by `Ctrl + Click (PC)` or `Cmd + Click (Mac)` on the function/variable. That opens the most recent reference manual. Or you can simply use [Reference Manual v4](https://www.tradingview.com/pine-script-reference/v4/) and [User Manual v4](https://www.tradingview.com/pine-script-docs/en/v4/index.html).